# Perform an operation during the last iteration of a for loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a loop that is parsing lines of a text file:

```
for line in file:
    if line.startswith('TK'):
        for item in line.split():
            if item.startwith('ID='):
                *stuff*
            if last_iteration_of_loop
                *stuff*
```

I need to do a few assignments, but I can't do them until the last iteration of the second for loop. Is there a way to detect this or to know if I'm at the last item of `line.split()`? As a note, the `items` in the second for loop are strings, and their content are unknown at runtime, so I can't look for a specific string as flag to let me know I'm at the end of the list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just refer to the last line outside the for loop:

```
for line in file:
    if line.startswith('TK'):
        item = None
        for item in line.split():
            if item.startwith('ID='):
                # *stuff*

        if item is not None:
            # *stuff*
```

The `item` variable is still available outside the for loop:

```
>>> for i in range(5):
...     print i
... 
0
1
2
3
4
>>>  print 'last:', i
last: 4
```

Note that if your file is empty (no iterations through the loop) `item` will not be set; this is why we set `item = None` before the loop and test for `if item is not None` afterwards.

If you must have the *last item that matched your test*, store that in a new variable:

```
for line in file:
    if line.startswith('TK'):
        lastitem = None
        for item in line.split():
            if item.startwith('ID='):
                lastitem = item
                # *stuff*

        if lastitem is not None:
             # *stuff*
```

Demonstration of the second option:

```
>>> lasti = None
>>> for i in range(5):
...     if i % 2 == 0:
...         lasti = i
...
>>> lasti
4
```

Comment: `else` to a `for` loop is completely pointless without a `break` statement in the loop.

Comment: Normally, I would agree with this approach (agreeing with @SvenMarnach). But what if the OP has to do something to `4` before printing it out? That would not work very well in this construct

Comment: I don't think it documents anything.  Even idiomatic use of `for`/`else` puzzles people, but this is really confusing.

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot about a `break` skipping any `else` clause...and so would have to tend to agree with your initial comment.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: That's better.

Comment: Thanks, looking better now.  And I'm really flabbergasted by how many upvotes the `else` block got. :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach: oh the fun of an upvote rush when people go 'oh yeah, forgot about that one!', even when actually the wrong approach. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Now as i understand this, will it only run up to the last valid line? I need to know if its the last item in the line, not the last line in the file.

Comment: @ZakParks: use the second option I gave you; `lastline` is the last matching line, if there was any.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, but by the time i got to the `if lastline is not None` line I would be out of the for loop. In my scenario i could still have thousands of lines to process in my file.

Comment: @ZakParks: corrected the answer, you want to know the last item in your inner loop, not in your outer loop, understood.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for line in file:
    if line.startswith('TK'):
        items = line.split()
        num_loops = len(items)
        for i in range len(items):
            item = items[i]
            if item.startwith('ID='):
                *stuff*
            if i==num_loops-1: # if last_iteration_of_loop
                *stuff*
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you can't just amend outside the final loop, but you may be able to make use of this - which works with any iterator, not just those of known length...

**not extensively tested and possibly not efficient**

```
from itertools import tee, izip_longest, count

def something(iterable):
    sentinel = object()
    next_count = count(1)

    iterable = iter(iterable)
    try:
        first = next(iterable)
    except StopIteration:
        yield sentinel, 'E', 0 # empty

    yield first, 'F', next(next_count) # first

    fst, snd = tee(iterable)
    next(snd)
    for one, two in izip_longest(fst, snd, fillvalue=sentinel):
        yield one, 'L' if two is sentinel else 'B', next(next_count) # 'L' = last, 'B' = body
```