# Speed up file I/O

Tags: python, file-io, python-3.x

I wrote this code to read a file as it is being written to control a lamp by toggling a switch in a game. The switch causes a string to be appended to the file. The program works, but it is slow. The file it reads from has over 15k lines to iterate through, and so can only update every other second or so. Is there a way to speed it up? Thanks!

```
import serial
s = serial.Serial(port = "COM3", baudrate = 9600)
def file_len():
    try:
        with open("file", "r") as f:
            for r, l in enumerate(f):
                pass
        return r + 1
    except:
        pass
def toggle(data, value):
    if(data.find("Clap Off!") == 0 and value == True):
        print("Off")
        s.write("RelayOff")
    elif(data.find("Clap On!") == 0 and value == False):
        print("On")
        s.write("RelayOn")
truth = False
while True:
    try:
        file = open("file", "r")
        for i, line in enumerate(file):
            if i == (file_len() - 2):
                toggle(data = file.readline(), value = truth)
                truth = not truth
        file.close()
    except:
        pass
```

EDIT:
I tried bypassing the while file_len function using this:

```
while True:
    try:
        file = open("file", "r")
        file.seek(-1, 2)
        #print(file.readline())
        toggle(data = file.readline(), value = truth)
        file.close()
        truth = not truth
    except:
        pass
```

But it raises the error "io.UnsupportedOperation: can't do nonzero end-relative seeks"
Is this just the way seek() works, or is there a way to seek backwards from the end of the file?

Comment: Your `s.write()` does not include a newline; unlike `print()`, using `file.write()` does not automatically add `\n`. Your data is being concatenated all on the very last line.

Comment: Also see [Perform an operation during the last iteration of a for loop in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11507901)

Comment: The whole purpose of this question is to find out how to AVOID iterating through the whole file, but just to target the line before the EOF.

Comment: Fair point; there are other duplicates for that here, I'm sure. Retracted my proposed dupe.

Comment: Quick FYI, if `file.seek(n, 2)` is `n` relative to the end of the file, then -1 means beyond the end of the file. You wanted to try 0 instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about your `file_len` function.  What does it have to do?  It reads the entire file each time you call it.

Think about your main loop.  It also reads the entire file.  And then what does it do for each line in the file?  It calls `file_len`.

How many times are you reading the entire file if the file has 5 lines?  10 lines?  100 lines?
15000 lines?

There are tools to help you find the hot spots in your program - for example the cProfile stdlib module.  However, just thinking about your program for a minute is faster than generating and analyzing a profile and can yield results just as good.

Comment: RESOLVED! I found the linecache module, which lets me read the contents of any line in the file.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that.

Comment: Is linecache inefficient? It at least speeds up my program to where it can check the file for updates about every 150 milliseconds, which is a VAST improvement.

Comment: It sounds like you avoided really understanding the cause of the problem in your program even though you found a way to make it run much faster.  That's the part I'm sorry about.